# Write a program to print all armstrong numbers between 1 and 1000

Tags: c++, loops

Write a program to print all armstrong numbers between 1 and 1000.

My Attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num=1, rem, sum, k;
    cout<<"Armstrong Numbers are: "<<endl;
    do
    {
        sum=0;
        k=num;
        do
        {
            rem=num%10;
            sum=sum+rem*rem*rem;
            num=num/10;
        }while(num!=0);
        if(sum==k)
        {
            cout<<k<<ends;
        }
        num++;
    }while(num<=1000);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When the above code is run, the output is seen as:
[image]

I don't know where is the error in the code. Please help me locate and correct the error.

Comment: After `while(num!=0);` - what value has `num`? Then you do `num++;` and then check `while(num<=1000);` it's an infinite loop. Maybe you need another counter there.

Comment: i dont know if this causes the problem, but you should initialize variables already when you declare them, or only declare them when you can initialize them, this would make your code much easier to read

Comment: Start your program in a debugger and step line by line through your code. Check the value of `num` in different lines, especially after `}while(num!=0);` and in `}while(num<=1000);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner loop is breaking `num`.

`num++;` should be `num = k + 1;` because the value of `num` is stored to `k` before the loop.